# Wildcard Branch Trigger not working for Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, build-pipeline, yaml

I have an Azure Devops build pipeline that has multiple branch triggers. I am using a wildcard to capture changes to branches under refresh/4.*. An example of a branch that I am targeting in this case would be refresh/4.13.0-refresh. But, the wildcard trigger is not firing when I push new refresh branches.

Here is the trigger definition yml

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - refs/tags/4.*
      - release/4.x
      - nightly-build
      - refresh/4.*
```

I was expecting this definition to trigger the build action when a new branch such as refresh/4.9.1-refresh is pushed to the remote repo. All of the other branch triggers here are succeeding. Including the tags trigger that uses a wildcard. My hunch is that - could be treated as a delimiter. But, I tried updating the trigger to refresh/4.*-refresh with no success.

The wildcard trigger works as defined when I override triggers from Azure Devops UI.  But, not from the yml definition. The pipeline is defined in `dev` and the definition is up to date.

I also tried wrapping the wildcard trigger in double quotes based on a github issue I saw related to Devops without success. I have also posted this question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74869171/wildcard-trigger-in-azure-devops-not-picking-up-branch-changes?noredirect=1#comment132136462_74869171

Comment: Is your up-to-date pipeline definition with the `refresh/4.*` trigger also present in your `refresh/4.9.1` branch? When deciding to run your pipeline Azure DevOps will use the pipeline yaml definition from the current branch being updated.